# android c2dm limit

Tags: android, limit, android-c2dm

anyone uses this service and has many user knows if there are any limit of registered devices on my app??

Google doesn't say nothing about this but I've read in a forum that 100 is the limit :(

I want to make a big app with at leads thousands of users but i don't know if i must pay for this limit, or if there aren't limit.

Here he says that 100 is limit for device registrations or something i can't understand.
http://www.stack-es.com/stackoverflow/es/bad-sides-of-c2dm-6112711.html

Please someone uses this can explain to me.

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Check [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/quotas)

"your sender account will be assigned the default quota, which currently corresponds to approximately **200,000** messages per day."

**Not 100..**

Thanks.

Comment: not 100 messages per day, i know they are 200,000msg/day, i mean, how many users can i have receiving notifications from my server. Registrations ID / app?

Comment: I think that may be user limit is not define if you any query then contact email to C2DM.

Comment: I have used C2DM more than 100 user but bot getting any error.